# trying to understand the Jacobi identity for vertex operator algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was having a look at James Lepowsky and Haisheng Li's "Introduction to Vertex Operator Algebras and their Representations" and when they give the Jacobi identity they have

$x_0^{-1}\delta(\frac{x_1-x_2}{x_0})Y(u,x_1)Y(v,x_2)-x_0^{-1}\delta(\frac{x_2-x_1}{-x_0})Y(v,x_2)Y(u,x_1)=x_2^{-1}\delta(\frac{x_1-x_0}{x_2})Y(Y(u,x_0)v,x_2). $

Here we have $\delta(x)=\Sigma_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} x^n$ and to expand, for example, $\delta(\frac{x_1-x_2}{x_0})$, you expand each negative power of $x_1-x_2$ as a power series in non-negative powers of the second variable.

I am just wondering how we can see that each expression involving a delta function is indeed a well-defined element of $\mathbb{C}[[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_0^{-1},x_1^{-1},x_2^{-1}]]$.

Comment: $600 000$-th question on MathSE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I know this question is old, just trying to give life to vertex algebras on StackExchange) In the formal calculus, if we have some $v(x)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} v_n x^n$, we use the following notation: $$v(x_1/x_2)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} v_n x_1^n x_2^{-n}.$$ We also have the binomial formula convention you mentioned: $$(x_1+x_2)^n:= \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}} {n\choose k} x_1^{n-k}x_2^k\in\mathbb{C}[[x_1,x_1^{-1},x_2]]$$ with $${n\choose k}=n(n-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot (n-k+1)/k!$$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, so we have $$(x_1-x_2)^n= \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}} {n\choose k}(-1)^k x_1^{n-k}x_2^k.$$

Hence if we expand e.g. the first delta function appearing in the Jacobi identity, we get $$\delta\bigg(\frac{x_1-x_2}{x_0}\bigg)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} (x_1-x_2)^nx_0^{-n}=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \bigg[\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}} {n\choose k}(-1)^k x_1^{n-k}x_2^k\bigg]x_0^{-n}.$$

Since the triple $(n-k,k,-n)$ is uniquely determined by $n$ and $k$, we do not have to worry about repeated terms in the double summation. For any fixed $n$ the sum $$\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}} {n\choose k}(-1)^k x_1^{n-k}x_2^kx_0^{-n}$$ is a well-defined element of $\mathbb{C}[[x_0,x_0^{-1},x_1,x_1^{-1},x_2,x_2^{-1}]]$ (since for a ring $R$ we have a canonical isomorphism $R[[x_1,x_2]]\cong R[[x_1]][[x_2]]$, and the natural extension of this to more variables holds by a simple induction-- this justifies removing the brackets from the earlier expression), so this suffices to conclude that $\delta(\frac{x_1-x_2}{x_0})$ exists.

Comment: Well... asking this question is certainly a very distant memory... but it's nice to finally see the answer!